# Spring property-placeholder configure positiveInteger

Tags: spring, properties, spring-security

I would like to map my ldapserver port setting to a property in my property file.
But when i use `${ldapserverport}` than i get the error:

> "The value '${ldapserverport}' of
>   attribute 'port' on element
>   'ldap-server' is not valid with
>   respect to its type,
>   'positiveInteger'."

Is there anyway to cast this property?
The other properties are working perfect.

my code:

```
<ldap-server id="ldapServer" url="${ldapserverurl}" 
        port="${ldapserverport}"
        manager-dn="${ldapserveruser}" 
        root="${ldapserverroot}"
        manager-password="${ldapserverpassword}"/>
```

Comment: Where did `<ldap-server>` come from?  That's not a Spring bean definition.

Comment: Why don't you provide the port in the url?

Comment: The ldap-server is part of the spring-security namespace. It is in a seperate xml file with this namespace as default, therefore there is no prefix. I could put the port in the url which would solve this specific problem. But i would like to know if it is possible to maybe cast this type of properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a shortcoming of the "custom namespace" approach used by some Spring config styles. While it allows configurations to be expressed very concisely, it's also highly specific, and doesn't automatically allow any of the generic substitution logic used by `<bean>`-style definitions, including property placeholders.

If the schema author has put in a hard-wired requirement for a given attribute to be an integer, then there's no getting around it - the author of the schema, and the code that parses it, would have to add explicit support for placeholders.  In this case, they haven't.

So if you want to use placeholders, you'll have to "explode" the `<ldap-server>` shortcut definition into the graph of underlying `<bean>` definitions. This isn't always easy, since the docs have to explain what beans are actually defined by `<ldap-server>`.

Comment: Oke, thats indeed a shortcomming. Thanks for the fast reply, i'll will try the solution of putting the port in the url.

Comment: I would suggest filing a JIRA. Luke and Rob have been good about fixing issues like this with property placeholder substitution.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <bean id="ldap-server" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.server.ApacheDSContainer">
      <constructor-arg index="0" value="dc=test,dc=com"/>
      <constructor-arg index="1" value="classpath:ldap_init.ldif"/>
      <property name="port" value="${ldapserverport}"/>
    </bean>
```

May require the following dependencies

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.directory.server</groupId>
      <artifactId>apacheds-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.directory.server</groupId>
      <artifactId>apacheds-core-entry</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.directory.server</groupId>
      <artifactId>apacheds-protocol-ldap</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.directory.server</groupId>
      <artifactId>apacheds-protocol-shared</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.directory.server</groupId>
      <artifactId>apacheds-server-jndi</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.directory.shared</groupId>
      <artifactId>shared-ldap</artifactId>
      <version>0.9.15</version>
    </dependency>
```